# How can I run a generator loop within my PyQt5 application without stopping it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pyqt, pyqt5

> My Generator Code

```py
def search(query):
    dir_path = os.path.realpath("C:/")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            if query.lower() in str(file).lower():
                yield (root, file)
        for directory in dirs:
            if query.lower() in str(directory).lower():
                yield (root, directory)
```

> I want to be able to fetch the results, showing them and run my application simultaneously.
>
> When I do this it hangs the program till the loop is over then show the results

````py
def pushButtonFunc():
    text = self.LocalSearchBar.text()
    newWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog(ProjectOSP)
    newWindow.resize(1201, 861)
    listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(newWindow)
    for root, file in search(text):
        ite = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(file)
        listWidget.addItem(ite)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible fixes:

1. The naive, simple method would be to call [`QApplication.processEvents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents-1). This iterates over the mainloop once, and can be called from anywhere in the same thread.
2. Another solution would be to somehow refactor your code to only do for example a single iteration every mainloop iteration. This works fine even if much of your work has to do with your GUI.
3. A third solution would be to factor out most of the work into a seperate QThread, and then send the data to your GUI thread with Qt's signals and slots. This is especially useful if very little of the work has to do with GUI changes.

Which of the last two is the best is highly dependent on your app, your specific usecase, and more code than is convienient to link here. It's really a call only you can make.

Comment: Thanks man the third solution brought me to something called QRunnable which I assume is type of QThread, it worked.